# WSACONNREFUSED when connecting to server

Tags: c++, winsock

I'm currently working on a server.  I know that the client side is working (I can connect to www.google.com on port 80, for example), but the server is not functioning correctly.  The socket has socket()ed, bind()ed, and listen()ed successfully and is on an accept loop.  The only problem is that accept() doesn't seem to work.  netstat shows that the server connection is running fine, as it prints the PID of the server process as LISTENING on the correct port.  However, accept never returns.  Accept just keeps running, and running, and if i try to connect to the port on localhost, i get a 10061 WSACONNREFUSED.  I tried looping the connection, and it just keeps refusing connections until i hit ctrl+c. I put a breakpoint directly after the call to accept(), and no matter how many times i try to connect to that port, the breakpoint never fires.

Why is accept not accepting connections?  Has anyone else had this problem before?

Known:

```
[breakpoint0]
if ((new_fd = accept(sockint, NULL, NULL)) == -1) {
   throw netlib::error("Accept Error"); //netlib::error : public std::exception
}
else {
   [breakpoint1]
   code...;
}
```

breakpoint0 is reached (and then continued through), no exception is thrown, and breakpoint1 is never reached.  The client code is proven to work.  Netstat shows that the socket is listening.

If it means anything, i'm connecting to 127.0.0.1 on port 5842 (random number).  The server is configured to run on 5842, and netstat confirms that the port is correct.

Comment: Did you make an exception for this port number on the firewall?

Comment: The program doesn't work even when i've disabled the firewall.

Comment: Running something like Wireshark on the server machine, can you see the SYN packets from the client side, trying to make the connection? Can you see, on the client machine, the SYN packets going out?

Comment: I'm running localhost<->localhost.  Running wireshark, however, i can see SYN/ACK packets coming in when i connect to a foreign host using the client.  If i find my network with IP and connect with to that address, i cannot find any SYN or ACK packets coming in to the computer from neither my IP nor the router's ip on the desired port. I also can't see any ICMP packets either, which would be the usual way to send the connection refused packet.  I can post full source if desired, but its rather large and don't *think* there's a problem setting up the socket.

Comment: I guess more code would be needed. perhaps stupid comment, I guess that you are using the same family, type and protocol for the server socket and client socket (AF_INET | SOCK_STREAM | IPPROTO_TCP)?

Comment: Is it possible to run the program on another computer and see if it works there?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using select and see if that one triggers. Because it seems as though accept never receives any connection:

```
fd_set mySet;
FD_ZERO(&mySet);
FD_SET(sockint, &mySet);
timeval zero = { 0, 0 };
int sel = select(0, &mySet, NULL, NULL, &zero);
if (FD_ISSET(sockint, &mySet)){
    // you have a new caller
    SOCKET newSocket = accept(sockint, NULL, NULL);
}
else{
    // still waiting
    <print>("Still waiting for connection.."); // whatever printfunction you use..
}
```